# Some help explaining javascript function

Tags: javascript

would you explain please, why this code is showing alert window with the text at the end of radio element:

```
<script>

    function markReply(el){
        alert(el.nextSibling.nodeValue);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        markReply();
    }); 

</script>
```

and this one does not:

```
<script>

    function markReply(el){
        return el.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var msg = markReply(); 
        alert(msg);
    });

</script>
```

there are 4 optional answers selected by radio element, like:

```
<input type="radio" name="choise" onclick="markReply(this);"/>....some text
```

Thank you!

Comment: One calls `alert`,  `alert(el.nextSibling.nodeValue);`, the other doesn't: `return el.nextSibling.nodeValue;`. Should be pretty obvious. Note that the calls you put inside the `ready` event handler are failing because you don't pass a value to `markReply`.

Answer (score 3):

The second script just returns the value, without doing anything with it.

Note that in both cases, the call from the document ready function is useless, and probably produces an `el is not defined` error in the console.

Comment: OK, when I assign the return value to the var msg and then try to alert that var, nothing happens. Where I am wrong?

Comment: @tetris555 The function expects a parameter (`el`) but you're not passing it anything.

Comment: Tetris, you can delete the entire `$(document)...` block, it's useless. The only function needed here is `markReply()`. But again, I don't really know what you are trying to do...

Comment: Generally it is a simple quiz, dynamically generated by php script, if I omit $(document).ready()... the alert window does not show. My point is this, when I click the answer, I want to store the nextSibling.nodeValue (the text) into a variable, and send it to php script for processing.

Comment: @tetris555: I really doubt that the `alert` you are seeing currently comes from the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` handler. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: it does, every new question is generated by a button, and pressing whichever radio option pop up alert window with the text, how can I store that text (this.nextSibling.nodeValue) into a variable for sending it to php script?

Comment: You may want to ask another question, more specific with what you are trying to accomplish. This one has been answered.

Comment: @tetris555: *"and pressing whichever radio option pop up alert"* If you read my comment again, you will notice that I never denied that. Yes, absolutely, the `alert` comes from clicking on  `<input type="radio" name="choise" onclick="markReply(this);"/>`. It does **not** come from the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. That code is broken and does not work. I only mentioned this in response to *"if I omit $(document).ready()... the alert window does not show"*, which is what I doubt, and here is the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/kdeavg2m/

Answer (score -1):

You're not passing any parameters to the markReply() function when you created a variable for it.

Try this:

```
var msg = markReply(el);
```

Comment: This will still only work on page load ... after that, the alert is only defined as a part of the document.ready ...

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Answer (score -1):

The script that does not alert the message is not working because the parameter of the function `markReply` is not there when the jquery is loaded.

`HTML`

```
<input type="radio" name="choise" id="choise"/>....some text
```

`JS`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#choise").click(function () {
           alert(markReply(this)); 
        });

    });

function markReply(el){
        return el.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4sgdton/

Comment: Why should the OP try this? How does that answer their question?

Comment: They would try this because it is a correct methodology ... however, I agree that this answer needs some work to answer the question.

Comment: well.. I just tried to give him the correct usage  while tried to write why is not working.